# How to set the max height of a Layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, css

I have to implement layout like this; The layout should wrap the content if the content within it is less. If the content goes beyond some size, like 300dp, it should be set to max heght(300dp) and that be able to scroll. Is there any properties to do like this, if not any workaround?

Comment: Have you find any solution on this ?

Comment: I'have found a solution to provide `maxHeight` to `ScrollView`. That solution can also be used for any type of view. Please read more at http://chintanrathod.com/maxheightscrollview-in-android-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 7):

You can find the display size of the device. according to the display size you can set `layout params`. for example, if the display size is less than `300dp` , you can set `height` as `wrap content`. if more than `300dp` means set `height` as `300dp`.

here is the example code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


    //here you can get height of the device.
   Log.d("check", metrics.heightPixels+"");
    if(metrics.heightPixels< 300)
    {
         this.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    }
    else {
         this.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,300);

    }
```

hope this one can help you.